# Quotient of finitely generated groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I am struggling with the next exercise of my HW:

Let $G_1, G_2, G_3$ be finitely generated groups such that $G_1 \times G_3 \cong G_2 \times G_3$. Let H be a finitely generated group.

Prove that $H \cong \frac{G_1}{N_1}$ for some $N_1 \unlhd G_1$ iff $H \cong \frac{G_2}{N_2}$ for some $N_2 \unlhd G_2$.

I'd appreciate any idea.

Thanks!

Comment: The first thing I'd do is clean up the problem statement by removing that pesky $H$. The problem becomes "Show every group $G_1/N_1$ is isomorphic to some group of the form $G_2/N_2$".

Comment: Your suggestion is the original phrasing of the problem but I found mine to be a little clearer